# Doesn't the $p$ depend on $m$

Tags: real-analysis, notation

Consider the following text:

[image]

where $p \in \mathbb Z$. Can you tell me please: doesn't $p$ depend on the $m$? So it is preferable maybe to write $p_m$? Or does $p$ not depend on $m$?

Comment: It does depend upon $m$.

Comment: Quite generally, the phrase "For a fixed ..." usually indicates constants introduced later on depend on that fixed value, unless they're specifically said not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed $p$ does depend on $m$, but adding the extra subscript as you request would be unnecessary notation.  The $p$ is not important, what's important is that $x$ is in an interval of width $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^m}$.